# Can I use a method in a component .jsp?

Tags: jsp, aem

I'm trying to write a simple service layer interface as per an article on Adobe's website (link shown in code header for reference).  When I try to load the page based on the template/component, I get an error: The method [methodname] is undefined for the type [componentname]_jsp.  I've tried using simpler, one-line methods, with public and no access modifier, different signature and return types, moving the method above the calling code, and always get the same result.  If I comment-out the method name and just include the code as a curly-brace-enclosed block, it compiles OK.  Could this not be possible in CQ/AEM v5.6.1 or am doing something wrong?

Entire code and exception shown below (with my various experimental versions commented-out and the original getPath(...) method omitted for simplicity).  Thank you in advance for your time.

```
<%--

    apipage component: implements service layer pages
    see: http://blogs.adobe.com/contentmanagement/2012/08/19/how-to-integrate-with-other-web-services-without-creating-osgi-packages/

--%><%
%><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
  <%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient,
                  org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams,
                  org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler,
                  org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod,
                  org.json.JSONObject"
%><%@page session="false" %><%
%><%
    if (request.getParameter("action") != null) {
        if (request.getParameter("action").equals("getFields") &&
                request.getParameter("param1") != null &&
                    request.getParameter("param2") != null) {
            //response.setContentType("application/json");
            //          out.write(getPath((String)request.getParameter("param1"), (String)request.getParameter("param2"));
            String str1 = "param1";
            String str2 = "param2";
            //out.write(getPath(str1, str2));
            int i = doNothing();
        }
    } else {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");
    }

    /*public*/ int doNothing() {
        return 1;
    }
%>

Error during include of component '/apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage'
Error Message:

org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 24 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp
The method doNothing() is undefined for the type apipage_jsp
21:             String str1 = "param1";
22:             String str2 = "param2";
23:             //out.write(getPath(str1, str2));
24:             int i = doNothing();
25:         }
26:     } else {
27:         response.setContentType("application/json");


An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp
Syntax error on token "int", new expected
28:         out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");
29:     }
30: 
31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {
32:         return 1;
33:     }
34: 


An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp
doNothing cannot be resolved to a type
28:         out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");
29:     }
30: 
31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {
32:         return 1;
33:     }
34: 


An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
28:         out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");
29:     }
30: 
31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {
32:         return 1;
33:     }
34: 


An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp
Void methods cannot return a value
29:     }
30: 
31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {
32:         return 1;
33:     }
34: 
35: /*

Processing Info:
Page    =   /content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI  
Resource Path   =   /content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI/jcr:content  
Cell    =   apipage 
Cell Search Path    =   apipage 
Component Path  =   /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage    
Sling Request Progress:

      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI.html
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI.html resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI)}
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI)} Using servlet /libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI.html handled by Servlet=/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (MobileUtil.isMobileResource() returns false)
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Applying Componentfilters
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp#0}
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Including resource JcrNodeResource, type=trp/components/layouts/apipage, superType=null, path=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI/jcr:content (SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI/jcr:content', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null')
      0 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=trp/components/layouts/apipage, superType=null, path=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI/jcr:content)}
     16 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_END{16,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=trp/components/layouts/apipage, superType=null, path=/content/trp/en/AfrescoAPI/jcr:content)} Using servlet /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp
     16 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Applying Includefilters
     16 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter
     16 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
     16 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
     16 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_START{/apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp#1}
    156 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG SCRIPT ERROR: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: //An error occurred at line: 24 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp/The method doNothing() is undefined for the type apipage_jsp/21:             String str1 = "param1";/22:             String str2 = "param2";/23:             //out.write(getPath(str1, str2));/24:             int i = doNothing();/25:         }/26:     } else {/27:         response.setContentType("application/json");///An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp/Syntax error on token "int", new expected/28:         out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");/29:     }/30: /31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {/32:       return 1;/33:   }/34: ///An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp/doNothing cannot be resolved to a type/28:         out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");/29:     }/30: /31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {/32:         return 1;/33:   }/34: ///An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp/Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement/28:         out.write("{\"error\":\"error\"}");/29:     }/30: /31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {/32:         return 1;/33:   }/34: ///An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp/Void methods cannot return a value/29:     }/30: /31: /*public*/ int doNothing() {/32:         return 1;/33:   }/34: /35: /*/
    156 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_END{140,/apps/trp/components/layouts/apipage/apipage.jsp#1}
    172 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html],order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=node /libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobile, values={component-optional=true, jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured}]), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=node /libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobiledebug, values={component-optional=true, jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured}]), Config(type=contentsync, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=node /libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-contentsync, values={component-optional=true, jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured}]), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
    172 (2013-11-14 10:41:01) TIMER_END{172,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scriptlets are the devil. You should never use scriptlets. Forget they even exist. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL. Use an MVC framework.

That said, here's why your code doesn't work. Everything inside `<%` and `%>` is code that is inside the service method of the servlet generated for the JSP. So, the following JSP:

```
<html>
    <% System.out.println("hello"); %>
</html>
```

is transformed by the container in a servlet that looks like this:

```
public class YourJsp extends JspServlet {

    public void jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        JspWriter out = createJspWriter(response);
        out.println("<html>");
        System.out.println("hello");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

You can deduce fom the above example that your code will be translated to something like

```
    public void jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...

        int doNothing() {
           return 1;
        }
    }
```

Which would thus declare a method inside another method. This would be invalid Java code, which is why your JSP is invalid.

To declare a method in a JSP, you need the following syntax (note the exclamation mark, which means "declaration"):

```
<%!
    int doNothing() {
        return 1;
    }
%>
```

The above code will be part of the class of the generated servlet, and not of its `jspService()` method.

That said: you should not have scriptlets in JSPs. Even less methods. Thos should be in Java source files. Scriptlets are obsolete for more than 10 years. The JSPs are view components, whose unique responsibility should be to generate HTML markup from data prepared by a controller, written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use declaration syntax (<%! ... %>):

```
<%! 
   public  int doNothing() { 
      return 1;
   } 
%>
<%
   int test = doNothing(); 
%>
```